# External HDD not showing when connected using extension cable 3

Tags: usb

I have Transcend , Adata and seagate HDD(2tb & 1tb) CASE which works perfectly fine when directly connected to TV screen in original cable.
When i use my USB 3 extension cable then HDD doesn't show up in TV screen and my HDD to fill blue light).
How can i fix this.

Comment: How long is the extension cable?

Answer (score 1):

USB standard doesn't define any extension cables, because the extra interconnect causes unstable and frequently unrecoverable degradation of signals. Plus extra voltage drop. And this is exactly what you see. An extender might work with some devices, or might not.

You can fix this either using an "active extender", which uses either a built-in USB hub, or USB 3.0 re-driver/re-timer, such that the entire cable is designed to compensate any extra signal deterioration.